# How to create a searchable, OCR'd PDF from PNG but use JPEG as pictures

Tags: linux, pdf, ocr, tesseract

I am in the process to digitalise my paper documents. For this, I start by scanning them to PNGs.

I already figured out how to use `tesseract` to OCR a batch of images and create a searchable PDF from that (using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75308930/8831116)).

Since I have the PNGs around anyway, I think I'd like to run OCR on these. In order to save disk space I'd like to use JPEGs for the final PDF, though.

Is there a way to achieve that? I am running Debian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this scenario is one that is very common for `tesseract`. However, the usual framing is that visually unchanged images should go to the PDF while images post-processed to suite the OCR are feed into `tesseract`.

The issue is addressed in [this comment](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/660#issuecomment-274213632). However, that explanation is rather abstract. I ended up doing the following:

1. Run tesseract: `ls *.png | tesseract -l $LANG -c textonly_pdf=1 - textonly pdf`
2. Convert PNGs to JPG: `fd . -e png --exec convert -quality 95 {} {.}.jpg`
3. Create an image-only PDF: `img2pdf *.jpg -o images.pdf`
4. Overlay the PDFs: `pdftk textonly.pdf multibackground images.pdf output result.pdf` (learned from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1171975))